# Pass array by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, argument-passing

I have a Fortran code in which I need to sort two arrays that are related to each other.  I would like to do this in a C++ function in order to leverage the built-in sort algorithm in the STL.  Because Fortran is pass-by-reference, all arguments to the C++ function must be pointers.  The following function `esort` sorts the arrays correctly, but does not return the correct values.  I believe this is because the pointers are passed by value, so the update at the end of the function has no effect.  How should I change my code to achieve the desired effect?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void esort(double* lambda, double* vecs, int* n) {

  double* res_lam = new double[*n];
  double* res_vec = new double[*n * *n];
  vector<pair<double, int> > order(*n);

  for (int i=0; i<*n; i++) {
    order[i] = make_pair(lambda[i], i);
  }

  sort(order.rbegin(), order.rend());

  for (int i=0; i<*n; i++) {
    pair<double, int> p = order.at(i);
    res_lam[i] = p.first;
    for (int j=0; j<*n; j++) {
      res_vec[*n*i + j] = vecs[*n*p.second + j];
    }
  }

  lambda = res_lam;
  vecs = res_vec;

  delete [] res_lam;
  delete [] res_vec;

  return;
}

int main() {

  double lambda[] = {0.5, 2.0, 1.0};
  double vecs[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
  int n = 3;

  esort(lambda, vecs, &n);

  cout << "lambda" << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cout << lambda[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "vecs" << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      cout << vecs[j*n + i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
lambda
0.5 2 1 
vecs
0.5 2 1 
0.5 2 1 
0.5 2 1
```

Desired Output:

```
lambda
0.5 1 2 
vecs
0.5 1 2 
0.5 1 2 
0.5 1 2
```

**EDIT:**  The ith element of `lambda` corresponds to the ith column of `vecs` (in Fortran's column-major order).  In order to avoid hassling with multi-dimensional arrays in C++, I am simply representing `vecs` as a 1D array within `esort`.  The point of `esort` is to sort `lambda` and then reorder `vecs` such that the ith element of `lambda` still corresponds to the ith column of `vecs`.

**EDIT 2:**  By placing `cout` statements inside `esort`, I have confirmed that `res_lam` and `res_vec` have the values that I want them to have at the end of the routine.  My issue is getting those values returned to the calling program.

Comment: _"Because Fortran is pass-by-reference, all arguments to the C++ function must be pointers"_ Wait what

Comment: Um you seem to be confused about pointers. If you really want to make use of C++'s features, this is really about the worst way to go about it..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm definitely open to suggestions on better ways of doing things.

Comment: @Alejandro, I just tried removing the `delete[]`s and I still get the same results.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yep just realized that, sorry!

Comment: You say the arrays are related to each other but, other than through code that (by your own admission) _does not accurately represent that relationship_, you don't tell us how that is. Please specify your requirements/goals in words.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, see edit above

Comment: Are you trying to pass an array by reference, or a pointer by reference? Because the title asks the former, while the code suggests the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that C++ passes all of its arguments by value, including pointers, meaning that assigning to `lambda` and `vecs` has no effect on the caller:  those variables only *point* to the data.  You need to copy your results into that pointed-to memory, as shown below by using `copy` from `<algorithm>`.  Also `rbegin` and `rend` are reverse iterators, which causes `sort` to sort backward from what you wanted; I changed it to `begin` and `end`.  I would further suggest using `vector` for your temporary `res_lam` and `res_vec` arrays.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

void esort(double* lambda, double* vecs, int* n) {

  vector<double> res_lam(*n);
  vector<double> res_vec(*n * *n);
  vector<pair<double, int> > order(*n);

  for (int i=0; i<*n; i++) {
    order[i] = make_pair(lambda[i], i);
  }

  sort(order.begin(), order.end());

  for (int i=0; i<*n; i++) {
    pair<double, int> p = order.at(i);
    res_lam[i] = p.first;
    for (int j=0; j<*n; j++) {
      res_vec[*n*i + j] = vecs[*n*p.second + j];
    }
  }

  copy(res_lam.begin(), res_lam.end(), lambda);
  copy(res_vec.begin(), res_vec.end(), vecs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void esort(double* lambda, double* vecs, int* n)`

When calling this function, it creates local pointer variables that reference the same memory address. In the code when the following is done:

```
lambda = res_lam;
vecs = res_vec;
```

It doesn't mean that you are changing the value of the memory address you passed as argument to the function, but rather the local pointer variable of the function `lambda` and `vecs` are now pointing to a different memory address.

Comment: Technically correct. Yet, re-allocating memory is a really stupid thing to do here. So this is not a good solution.

Comment: @Ediac, so how could I fix my code?  I tried `void esort(double* &lambda, double* &vecs, int* n)` but then I get segfault whenever I try to access elements of `lambda` or `vecs`.

Comment: Yeah i know, just highlighting the OP's faults :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, could you elaborate on how I might still achieve my goals without reallocating memory?

Comment: @astay13 Went away for a moment, but it seems like there are new answers now

Comment: @astay13: Depends what your goals are.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Pointer to Pointer Concept.

```
void esort(double** lambda, double** vecs, int* n)
```